# Retrieve Values from a List within an Object

Tags: android, list, object, nested

> I'm trying to retrieve a value from an Object which sits within an ArrayList
>   within another Object.

The basic structure is:

+++++

**Book** Object -> List of **Author** Objects -> **Author** Object -> Author first name **variable**

+++++

And I would like to **access** the **first name** of the **first Author** for a given Book

+++++

I have created a **"Book" Class** which looks like the following:

```
public class Book {

private String mTitle;

private List<Author> mAuthors;

public Book(String title, List<Author> authors) {
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mAuthors = authors;
}

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public List<Author> getmAuthors() {
    return mAuthors;
}
}
```

This class also contains a **list of Author-Objects**:

```
public class Author {

private String mFirstName;
private String mLastName;

public Author(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.mFirstName = firstName;
    this.mLastName = lastName;
}

public String getmFirstName() {
    return mFirstName;
}

public String getmLastName() {
    return mLastName;
}
}
```

I then create an the l**ist of Author instances** in the **MainActivity:**

```
 ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

    authors.add(new Author("Hans", "Schwabe"));
```

And **use this list** when creating the **book instance**

```
Book buch = new Book("Säulen der Erde",authors);
```

When I then try to **access** the **name of the first Author** in the list I use the following code:

```
List<Author> authorArrayList = new ArrayList<Author>();
authorArrayList = buch.getmAuthors();
authorArrayList.get(1).getmFirstName();
```

And at this point my app **keeps crashing**.

**

> Hence: What would be the right way to retrieve the first name of the
>   first author from the list?

**

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you have 1 author and you are trying to retrieve it from index 1. Index should be 0. Indexing in programming is starting from 0.

If you write

authorArrayList.get(0).getmFirstName();

It should work

Comment: That's it... Thank you so much Dajf!